# how to save entities in a relation to database in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, database, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application with two entities in a relationship. MeetingSetting and MeetingTime meetingSetting can have unlimited meetingTimes. So far the databases are generating without problem, but When I try to save my Entity they are saved but different from each other, they are saved independently. Meaning MeetingName which is a foreign key inside MeetingTime is not saved but seen as null (I debugged and tried finding out why but could not find anything) THe other values are saved-

could someone point me out what my error is?

this is the json I am sending:

```
{
   "meetingName":"TEst",
   "meetingPw":"",
   "meetingTime":[
      {
         "date":"2021-05-31",
         "startTime":"15:30",
         "endTime":"16:30"
      },
      {
         "date":"2021-06-21",
         "startTime":"15:30",
         "endTime":"17:30"
      },
      {
         "date":"2021-06-21",
         "startTime":"11:01",
         "endTime":"11:01"
      }
   ]
}
```

MeetingSettings:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "meeting_settings")
@Data

public class MeetingsSetting {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "meeting_name", unique = true)
    private String meetingName;

    @Column(name = "meeting_url")
    private String meetingUrl;

    @Column(name = "meeting_pw")
    private String meetingPw;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "meeting_Name", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<MeetingTime> meetingTime = new HashSet<>();
}
```

MeetingTime:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "meeting_times")
@Data
public class MeetingTime {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "meeting_date")
    private String date;

    @Column(name = "start_time")
    private String startTime;

    @Column(name = "end_time")
    private String endTime;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "meeting_name" ,insertable = false, updatable = false , referencedColumnName = "meeting_name")
    private MeetingsSetting meeting_Name;
}
```

this is how I try to save the entity:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/meetingSetting")
public class MeetingSettingController {

    @Autowired
    MeetingSettingService meetingSettingService;

    @PostMapping("/")
    public void saveMeeting(@RequestBody MeetingsSetting meetingsSetting){
        meetingSettingService.saveMeeting(meetingsSetting);

    }


}
```

My service calls the save method of an jpaRepository.

Answer (score 0):

In a bi-directional One to Many, you have to synchronize both sides of the association.

You can simply iterate over all `MeetingTime` objects and set the corresponding `MeetingSetting` to it.

Your `MeetingSettingService`'s `saveMeeting` method could do this:

```
public void saveMeeting(MeetingsSetting meetingsSetting) {
    // ... 
    
    // here you're synchronizing both sides of the association
    meetingsSetting.getMeetingTime()
            .forEach(mt -> mt.setMeetingSetting(meetingSetting));
    // ...
    repository.save(meetingSetting);
}
```

Comment: Hi,
I was about to try your solution. But can u explain me the part with mt.setMeetingSetting? This part gives me an error not being able to find it

Comment: I was able to make the method at least error free, but meetingsSetting seems to be giving a new error: Method threw 'java.lang.StackOverflowError' exception. Cannot evaluate com.cbc.coorporateblinddateservice.entities.meetinsSetting.MeetingsSetting.toString()

I debugged and this is what the output was when I looked at meetingTimes

Comment: Hi, So I found a solution but, I do not know if that is best practice. I took your method and instead of setting the Object meetingSetting I have taken put a meeting_name variable inside the meetingTimes and set it with meetingSettings.getName. This works How I wish for it to work. But I do not know if that is best practice. I will post my solution as a new answer maybe you or someone else can give me a best practice example

Comment: The `java.lang.StackOverflowError` occurs because you reach a infinite recursion. That's the normal behavior. There are some ways to prevent this, but, in your case, just remove the `meetingSetting` from the MeetingTime's `toString()` method.

Comment: But I do not have any toString method haha. Or What do you mean

Comment: Yes, you do have `toString()`. `@Data` from lombok does generate it for you. And yourself posted the error 'java.lang.StackOverflowError' exception. Cannot evaluate com.cbc.coorporateblinddateservice.entities.meetinsSetting.MeetingsSetting. **toString()**

Comment: Hi,
If I remove @data I am getting an error for every set method we implemented

Comment: Yes, because `@Data` generates much more than `toString()`. This is well documented here: https://projectlombok.org/features/Data . . . You have to manually implement the `toString()` method, remove `@Data` and then add `@Getter`, `@Setter` to your class.

Answer (score 0):

Solution to my question, I am not sure if this is a good or correct way of solving this maybe someone can advice me a better solution:

```
 @Entity
    @Table(name = "meeting_times")
    @Data
    public class MeetingTime implements Serializable {
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long id;
    
        @Column(name = "meeting_date")
        private String date;
    
        @Column(name = "start_time")
        private String startTime;
    
        @Column(name = "meeting_name")
        private String meeting_name;
        THIS IS THE PART WHICH IS CALLED FROM THE METHOD INSIDE MEETINGSCONTROLLER
        @Column(name = "end_time")
        private String endTime;
    
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "meeting_name" ,insertable = false, updatable = false, referencedColumnName = "meeting_name")
        private MeetingsSetting meetingName;
    }
```

MeetingsTime Entity:

```
@RestController
        @RequestMapping("/api/meetingSetting")
        public class MeetingSettingController {
        
            @Autowired
            MeetingSettingService meetingSettingService;
        
            @PostMapping("/")
            public void saveMeeting(@RequestBody MeetingsSetting meetingsSetting){
                meetingsSetting.getMeetingTime()
                        .forEach(mt -> mt.setMeeting_name(meetingsSetting.getMeetingName()));
                // ...
                meetingSettingService.saveMeeting(meetingsSetting);
        
            }
        
        
        }
```

Comment: This will also going to cause `java.lang.StackOverflowError` when `MeetingsSetting#toString()` is called after retrieving it from the database or when you try to serialize the object to JSON. You'll probably see this during the development.
This has no gain over `mt.setMeetingSetting(meetingSetting)` in my opinion.